# How can I get the redirect urls for a url

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I want to store the redirect urls . Suppose I have a website and it redirects from site A to Site B then to Site C.
Suppose I am requesting this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwg3I.png) and it redirects to

[image]

How can I get the list of redirect urls in php or in javascript?

Comment: You could probably make a chrome extension using javascript to get the url of the browser and then store it

Comment: without extension is it possible ?

Comment: you can use curl function and get headers and you will get the location url in every redirect in headers.

Comment: no we cant, I have tried that as well, what happens is next redirect url does not respond while hitting through code

Answer (score 0):

$myTotalRedirectIRl[] = $_SERVER['HTTPS_REFERER'];

set upper variable to all page

print_r($myTotalRedirectUrl);

Answer (score 0):

Every time as page is redirecting, in each page get the url of page and store in browsers internal storage using javascript

So that you can access it later

```
<script>
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") 
    {
        var URL =  window.location.href;
        // Store URL in page 1
        localStorage.setItem("page1", URL);
    } 
</script>

<script>
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") 
    {
        var URL =  window.location.href;
        // Store URL in page 2
        localStorage.setItem("page2", URL);
    } 
</script>

<script>
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") 
    {
        // Retrieve in page 3
        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("page1");
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("page2");
    } 
</script>
```